# How to make the standard music player find my files

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

My App downloads some mp3 files to sdcard. I want to play them with other music players installed on the device. But the other music players don't automatically find my downloaded files. How can I force the MediaScanner to run so that my media files will be playable from the stock Music application?

I download the files using this code

```
public void run() {
        loaded = 0;
        try{                
        java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream());
        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(FileName);
        java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int x=0;
        while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0 && !stop){
            loaded += x;
            bout.write(data,0,x); 
        }
        fos.flush();
        bout.flush();
        fos.close();
        bout.close();
        in.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
}
```

Comment: It should do it automatically.  You may have to restart the music player after you download the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the scan of media file with a broadcast:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder that your files are in do not have a file called ".nomedia" in them.  That file tells the MediaScanner not to check there.

(note: there is a "." in front of nomedia, which means it may be hidden)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy 'single file based solution':

Whenever you **add** or **remove** a file, let MediaStore Content Provider knows about it using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageAddedOrDeleted)));
```

Main advantage: work with any mime type supported by MediaStore

Note:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

is too expensive and scan everything. My advice: if you can, use the 'per file' approach.